# Adding elements and deleting them with IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, internet-explorer

I have a page, where I can add multiple rows to represent IP Addresses, everything works fine in Chrome, but I noticed I can't delete new rows that have been added. If the rows were there from the beginning it works. This only happens on IE.

My page's code looks like this:

```
@section Scripts
{
    <script>
        jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
            $('#add-room').on('click', function () {
                jQuery.get('/MyWebUi/Groups/AddAuthorizedClient').done(function (html) {
                    $('#rooms-list').append(html);
                });
            });
        });

        function DeleteRow(id) {
            var element = document.getElementById("AuthClientId" + id);
            element.parentElement.removeChild(element);
            //document.getElementById("AuthClientId" + id).remove();
        };
    </script>
}

<h2>Group</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm("Save", "Groups"))
{
    @Html.EditorFor(x => x)
    @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.Id)

    <h4>Authorized clients</h4>
    <div id="rooms-list">
        @Html.EditorForMany(x => x.AuthorizedClients, x => x.Index)
    </div>

    <input type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="add-room" value="Add client" />
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
}
```

The first function calls this method:

```
    [OutputCache(NoStore = true, Duration = 0, VaryByParam = "*")]
    public ActionResult AddAuthorizedClient()
    {
        var building = new Group();
        building.AuthorizedClients.Add(new ModelAbstraction.AuthorizedClient() { Id = Guid.NewGuid() });

        return View(building);
    }
```

And my editor template for AuthorizedClient looks like:

```
<div class="editorRow" id=@string.Concat("AuthClientId", Model.Id.ToString())>
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-body">
            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(x => x.IpAddress, new { title = ModelMetadata.FromLambdaExpression(x => x.IpAddress, ViewData).Description })
                @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.IpAddress, new { @class = "form-control" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.IpAddress)
            </div>

            @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.Id)
            <input type="button" class="btn btn-danger" id="delete-client" value="Delete client" onclick="DeleteRow(&quot;@Model.Id.ToString()&quot;)"/>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I think the issue may be that in IE I don't see in the debugger (the new created html after clicking Add), shows up in the DOM Explorer window but not in the debugger... and the delete method isn't being called apparently

Comment: Which IE version are you testing against? Are you sure the method isn't being called, have you tried adding console.log, what does it log? Do you see any errors in the console?

Comment: There is a lot of bad code here including invalid html because of duplicate `id` attributes. Give you button a class name (say `class="delete"`) and use `$(document).on('click', '.delete', function() { $(this).closest('.editorRow').remove(); });`

Comment: @Olga I've tried both edge and 10. I've added alert messages, so I know for sure it only gets called on not new elements and only happens with IE. No errors in the console.

Comment: @StephenMuecke I couldn't find the duplicate IDs, however the idea of adding the class delete and the jquery code works great, thanks!

Comment: You cannot see the multiple inputs with `id="delete-client"`? :) (and you should delete the pointless `id` attribute on the outer `<div>`)

Comment: @StephenMuecke you're right, I guess I wasn't looking at the right part.. and yeah the outer div id is now useless with your solution... thanks again!

Comment: @StephenMuecke since your suggestion solves the problem, could you maybe convert it to answer?